# Unicode characters disappear in mail attachment name

Tags: c#, email, unicode, smtp

I develop an app, which needs to send zipped files via e-mail (in attachments). Everything is good  except one thing: cyrillic (or other unicode) characters in attachment name dissappears. They work fine in message name and message body, but not in attachment.

I use following code for attachment:

```
var attachment = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);

ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;

disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(file);
disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);            
disposition.Size = new FileInfo(file).Length;
disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;            
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

And use SmtpClient Class to send E-mail. I tried some workarounds found on SO, like

```
att.Name = "история-болезни.doc";  // non-english filename    
att.Name = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(att.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

But got nothing... My logs says that e-mail goes to server with correct attachment names and i also tried to send such an e-mail manually (not programmatically) and it also worked good.

So, how can i workaround this problem? I found some patch for .Net framework, but it's not good for because i have to publish my app to many different clients and i don't want to install patches on their computer before the app can work properly.

**UPD.**
[image: Letter Sample (In Outlook)]

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064/en-us)?

Comment: @OğuzSezer, as i mentioned, i'd better use workaround without such installable hotfixes because it'll complicate app deploy. Do I have any other choises?

Comment: I guess there is no other solution, I've faced the same problem and that was the only solution worked for me. If you find something else please let me know as well :)

Comment: @OğuzSezer, Have you tried framework upgrade? Maybe it'll solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, I'm still on V4.0 with the hotfix. I'm not planning upgrading framework version of my application in the near future.

Comment: @OğuzSezer thank you very much, so i'll go on for this hotfix :)

Comment: @OğuzSezer, Now i have another trouble: hotfix says that my OS is oncompatible for it and neither framework version upgrade helps...

Comment: Can you post the (applicable sections) of the source of the message sent by your application?

Comment: @mti2935, added screenshot of the letter

Comment: FWIW, you are URL-encoding the 'name' parameter but not the Content-Disposition's filename parameter (which takes precedence over the Content-Type's name parameter). However, even if you URL-encode the filename parameter, it's wrong because the name/filename parameters need to change their syntax to name*=... and filename*=... respectively. They also need to have the charset encoded into the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that System.Net.Mail's attachment filename encoder is broken and that means there's probably not any way to solve this while continuing to use it.

What you can do instead, though, is use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which properly encodes attachment filenames. It allows you to cast from a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage into a MimeKit.MimeMessage which should make it fairly easy to port over.

Edit:

To create the same message in MimeKit and MailKit, the code would look something like this:

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin?";

var builder = new BodyBuilder ();

// Set the plain-text version of the message text
builder.TextBody = @"Hey Alice,

What are you up to this weekend? Monica is throwing one of her parties on
Saturday and I was hoping you could make it.

Will you be my +1?

-- Joey
";

// Add an attachment
builder.Attachments.Add (file);

var attachment = builder.Attachments[0];

// setting the attachment.FileName will set the Content-Disposition's filename
// parameter as well as the Content-Type's name parameter.
attachment.FileName = "история-болезни.doc";

// FWIW, very few, if any, mail clients actually care about these fields...
// they are optional and can be ignored.
//var disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
//disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime (file);
//disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime (file);
//disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime (file);
//disposition.Size = new FileInfo (file).Length;

// Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody ();

// Now send via MailKit's SmtpClient
smtpClient.Send (message);
```

Comment: No problem! I'm working on adding support for the new Internationalized Email standards as well (just adding finishing touches now).